# Where in Magento is the homepage pulled?

Tags: php, magento, content-management-system, magento-1.7

I'm assuming it's one of the app layout files - I want to write a hook in my mobile template to pull a different CMS homepage.

Edit: To clarify, I want to achieve having a different cms page pulled for the hompage of a mobile version of the store vs. the desktop version. Since you can only set one default CMS page in magento admin, seems like there needs to be some custom coding in the mobile template files.

Comment: By default I think it's a static page that uses one of the basic templates (right-column, left-column, single-column). Unless you have it overriden, check the CMS in the Magento Admin.

Comment: Check edit above. I'm trying to pull a different CMS page for the mobile version of the site, I think meaning I'll need to override it somewhere in the mobile template. Just not sure where to override it!

Comment: You can create Exceptions in the Design tab to use a different theme based on the user agent. This is the magentorific way to do it. [Here's a guide on how to do it](http://magebase.com/magento-tutorials/magento-design-exceptions-explained/)

Comment: I've done all the Exceptions, and they're working just fine. However, the same CMS homepage is being pulled for the desktop and mobile version. I'm trying to grab a different CMS homepage for the mobile version

Answer (score 6, accepted):

One of the things I love about Magento is the ability to accomplish a lot of things, just by playing with layout files.

I'll refer to Alan Storm's image to illustrate how I accomplished this exact task without having to change code (I hope you don't mind Alan).

[image]

As you can see with the image above, the Full Action Name is cms_index_index. You can find this information with debugging tools, like Commerce Bug.

As we have the action name, we can change the layout files to point to a mobile-specific home page. In this method the mobile-specific home page is actually a static block.

Once you have set up your mobile-specific content, you can add the following to your mobile template local.xml file, to use this block for your home page:

```
<cms_index_index>
      <block type="cms/block" name="cms_page"><action method="setBlockId"><block_id>mobile_home</block_id></action></block>
</cms_index_index>
```

In this case I have set up a mobile_home static block. It will use the same layout name  as the desktop home page, but this has already been overridden in the mobile template.

This may not be the best way, but it doesn't involve code changes.

Comment: Nice — I wouldn't have thought to do that.  (Programmer's disease)

Comment: Thanks for the solution CCBlackburn. The default homepage is no longer being pulled. However, no static block is getting pulled from this either - the cms section is blank (check http://vapetropolis.ca on a mobile device). I've created a mobile_home static block, and I've also tried using an existing static block.

Comment: What's the content for that block, I'm not sure what's supposed to b there and not.

Additionally, can you double check that cms_index_index layout declaration in the local.xml is the only one defined and that there's not one being defined in cms.xml in the same folder?

Answer (score 5):

It's probably not as straight forward as you'd like, but here's how this works.

The request for the homepage is routed to the `indexAction` method of the `Mage_Cms_IndexController` class.

[image]

If you take a look at the `indexAction` method you can see Magento uses the `renderPage` method of the `cms/page` helper object to render the contents of the page

```
#File: app/code/core/Mage/Cms/controllers/IndexController.php
public function indexAction($coreRoute = null)
{
    $pageId = Mage::getStoreConfig(Mage_Cms_Helper_Page::XML_PATH_HOME_PAGE);
    if (!Mage::helper('cms/page')->renderPage($this, $pageId)) {
        $this->_forward('defaultIndex');
    }
}
```

The `$pageId` is pulled from Magento's system configuration, and is the URL identifier of the CMS page.

If you hop to the `renderPage` method

```
#File: app/code/core/Mage/Cms/Helper/Page.php
public function renderPage(Mage_Core_Controller_Front_Action $action, $pageId = null)
{
    return $this->_renderPage($action, $pageId);
}
```

it wraps the call to the protected `_renderPage` method.  If you hop to THAT method, the page loading code is the following portions.

```
#File: app/code/core/Mage/Cms/Helper/Page.php
protected function _renderPage(Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Action  $action, $pageId = null, $renderLayout = true)
{
    $page = Mage::getSingleton('cms/page');
    //...
    if (!$page->load($pageId)) {
        return false;
    }
    //...
}
```

This loads the CMS Page object for the homepage.  Notice the model is a singleton, which means other code that instantes the singleton later will have the same page. After this, standard Magento page rendering happens.  Possibly relevant to your interests, the content layout blocks end up looking like this

[image]

Meaning the block HTML for the CMS page is rendered by the following code in `Mage_Cms_Block_Page`

```
#File: app/code/core/Mage/Cms/Helper/Page.php
protected function _toHtml()
{
    /* @var $helper Mage_Cms_Helper_Data */
    $helper = Mage::helper('cms');
    $processor = $helper->getPageTemplateProcessor();
    $html = $processor->filter($this->getPage()->getContent());
    $html = $this->getMessagesBlock()->toHtml() . $html;
    return $html;
}
```

The `getPage` method instantiates the same singleton we mentioned above.  The other code is what replaces CMS page `{{...}}` directives with their actual content.

If I was approaching this project, I'd consider a class rewrite for the `Mage_Cms_Model_Page` object that looks something like this.

```
public function load($id, $field=null)
{
    if( ... is mobile site ... AND  ... $id is for the home page ...)
    {
        $id = ... ID of the mobile site, hard coded or pulled from custom config ...;
    }

    return parent::load($id, $field);
}
```

There's also the `cms_page_render` event which fires after the page has loaded in the `_renderPage` method.  You could try reloading the passed in page  object with a different ID in the observer. You could also consider something in the `model_load_after` or `model_load_before` events — although that gets trickier to do since you can't directly change the ID.

For code that's not going to leave a single client's system, I usually opt for the rewrite these days, since it's quicker (less expensive for clients) and has less complications (i.e. getting at and changing the information you need) during development.  The trade-off is a possible future conflict with someone else who's rewriting the class.

Your milage/philosophy may vary.

Good luck!

Comment: With the ``cms_page_render`` event approach, I tried ``$observer->getEvent()->setPage($new_page)`` but it doesn't work. Does ``Mage::dispatchEvent()`` pass in arguments by reference? If so, how do I reload the same page object with a different Id without loosing that reference?